# Bootstrap Modal flashes/disappears instantly - ASP.NET gridview RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, modal-dialog

Good morning everybody. I seem to be stuck between a rock and a hard place and fear I may be missing something incredibly simple. I am currently developing a webforms application using an ASP.NET GridView control.

I have a bootstrap modal that is intended to display gridview row details through an ASP button on each row. I understand there are other posts on this topic but my issue seems to be a little different.

The button I use to toggle the bootstrap modal is in an asp control:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approval Information">
     <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Button Text="Stats" runat="server" CommandName="ApprovalModal" type="button" class="btn btn-info" OnClientClick="return false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This button can currently toggle my modal just fine. The problem is, I want to subscribe to the RowCommand event in GridView so I can change the text of the ASP Literal control in the modal to display Row stats for each individual row when clicked:

```
  protected void gvwApprovals_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ApprovalModal")
        {
            approvalModalText.Text = "Some Unique Row Stats";
            approvalModalText.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The only way I can subscribe to this event and have it fire is if I take out `OnClientClick="return false"`

However, if I take that out of the ASP button, I subscribe to the event, but then the bootstrap modal now just flashes and disappears.

Here is my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="display: block;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Approval Information - Relevant Statistics</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <asp:Literal ID="approvalModalText" runat="server" Text='placeholder' Visible="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here? Available to clarify any further questions. Fairly new to ASP controls in general, so I'm not sure if there's something super simple I might just be totally unaware of.

**EDIT:**

Of course there is a post that happens to fire the RowCommand which reloads the page and the modal disappears. Thanks to Alex for pointing it out to me in the comments (I knew it was something dumb and simple). Must use `RegisterStartupScript` in Row Command handler to show the modal rather than just doing a straight toggle. jQuery here I come.

Comment: in `rowcommand` handler `registerstartupscript` which show modal.

Comment: Wouldn't this require me using jQuery? Every example I've seen with that approach uses jQuery.

Comment: `bootstrap` requires jquery so do you.

Comment: I'm aware that bootstrap requires jQuery, but I guess my question is - Why can I toggle the modal perfectly fine until I remove `OnClientClick="return false"` from the button? What is the default behavior behind the scenes that is making it immediately disappear?

Comment: the page `post`s to fire `rowcommand` server-side handler so modal (client side) disappear when the page reloads. this is why you need `.registerstartupscript` to show modal.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it might have something to do with a post.